# programming style conventions: [+], [-], [*], [!]

Tags: python, styles, convention

I couldn't find an answer through google search because apparently google won't allow searches for punctuation.

When reporting stdout of a program (I'm using Python), does anyone have any style rules for `[+]` `[-]` `[*]` `[!]` at the beginning of a line? e.g.

```
[+] Searching for item one...
[-] Not found: item one.
[+] Searching for item two...
[!] Found: item two.
```

I could come up with a system myself, but because I see these around occasionally, I was wondering whether someone knew of a generally accepted system for usage?

Comment: I think it's entirely dependent on the information you're outputting...

Comment: I use these in my console programs sometimes but don't have particular rules, usually [+] is success, [-] is error, [.] or [ ] is waiting for something.

Comment: not to my knowledge theres a generalized system like that, it completely depends on your output

Comment: If you're talking about logging output, typically, I just use the words to represent themselves, like `ERROR`, `INFO`, or `DEBUG`. If it represents waiting, I usually put `...`

Comment: Honestly, I never thought of this. Nice question lol :)

Comment: it's also used in the logging of the [pwn moule](http://docs.pwntools.com/en/stable/log.html#module-pwnlib.log)